# Jquery typing effect on scroll bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, typescript

Hi I have some js code that do typing effect on my web page it start typing when you scroll down end of page. For first it work normally  but when you start scroll faster down to up the typing effect goes crazy how can I fix that

[demo page](http://conceptmds.com/demo/work)

code

```
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
    var elem = $(".hello-page");
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var blockTop = elem.offset().top;
    var docHeight = $(document).height();
    var windowH = $(window).height();

    if (scrollTop >= blockTop) {
        var helloPageA = $(".hello-page").find("a");
        var text = helloPageA.attr("data-text");
        helloPageA.text('');
        $.each(text.split(''), function (i, letter) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                helloPageA.html(helloPageA.html() + letter);
            }, 150 * i);
        });
    } else {
        elem.find("a").text('');
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xezs6h0x/)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Yeah during the for loop if you scroll out it messes up you need to break the loop on scroll out event

Comment: I try do that with flags wit cleartimeout but no changes

Comment: Hmm, I'll look into how to fix your problem but meanwhile perhaps use GSAP for animation ? https://greensock.com/splittext-example

Comment: GSAP is a js library?

Comment: it will be fine to resolve problem without any libraries or plugins :)

Comment: You might want to consider not changing the html but creating divs for the letters to fade in or delay so that it gets the break event from Jquery and not manually.

Comment: This should do the trick http://jsfiddle.net/u3ojjx8r/1/ - the main idea to split the queue generation and actual rendering.

Comment: oooooooooo this is awsome thanl you

Comment: What I can see with the example is to start typing when you reach a particular position on the page. I believe using some [plugin](https://github.com/amitguptagwl/shabdawali) can make your job easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here is the solution - http://jsfiddle.net/u3ojjx8r/1/
I borrowed initial structure of the code from previous answer here and it was removed unfortunately, therefore I can't mention one of the co-authors. Though the code looked quite similar to topic-starter's one.

The idea of the code below is to separate the queuing of characters to render and the actual rendering. Another important improvement is always have control over timeouts, i.e. never schedule more than one timeout. That allows you to cancel them any time without unpredicted/uncontrolled behavior.

```
var timeoutVar;
var queue = [];
var drawQueueTimeout = -1;
var helloPageA = $(".hello-page").find("a");

function pushQueue (element) {
    console.log('pushQUeue', element.char);
    queue.push(element);
    checkQueue();
}

function flushQueue () {
    console.log('flushQueue');
    queue = [];

    clearTimeout(drawQueueTimeout);
    drawQueueTimeout = -1;
}

function checkQueue () {
    console.log('checkQueue', queue.length, drawQueueTimeout);
    if (queue.length > 0 && drawQueueTimeout < 0) {
        console.log('schedule drawQueue');
        drawQueueTimeout = setTimeout(drawQueue, 150);
    }
}

function drawQueue () {
    drawQueueTimeout = -1;

    console.log('draw queue');
    if (queue.length > 0) {
        var element = queue.shift();
        console.log('drawQueue', element.char);
        helloPageA.html(helloPageA.html() + element.char);
    }

    checkQueue();
}

$(window).scroll(function (e) {
    var elem = $(".hello-page");
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var blockTop = elem.offset().top;
    var docHeight = $(document).height();
    var windowH = $(window).height();

    if (scrollTop + windowH == docHeight) {
        // Empty anything typed so far
        helloPageA.empty();
        flushQueue();

        var text = helloPageA.attr("data-text");
        helloPageA.text('');
        $.each(text.split(''), function (i, letter) {
            pushQueue({
                char: letter,
                index: i
            });
        });

    } else {
        helloPageA.empty();
        flushQueue();
    }
});
```